# Problemas para deletar números repetidos em um ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, arraylist

Estou tendo problemas para retirar números repetidos de um `ArrayList`, aqui está o trecho do código:

```
for( int i = 0 ; i < houses.size(); i++ ) {   
   for( int j = 1; j < houses.size(); j++ ) {
        if(houses.get(i).equals(houses.get(j)) && i!=j){
            houses.remove(j);
        }
    }
 }
```

Ele deleta de forma correta a maioria dos elementos repetidos, mas em alguns casos deleta alguns a mais, queria muito saber o que há de errado com este código, pois não consigo descobrir.

Comment: Deleta a mais ou a menos? Não consigo imaginar por que estaria deletando a mais, poderia dar um exemplo de onde isso acontece?

Comment: Números armazenados como string?

Comment: e se usar um Set?

Comment: Você está removendo elementos durante a iteração. Isso dá problema porque bagunça os índices.

Comment: Qual é o tipo da lista? Pode por mais partes do código?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu o problema? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso. Você estaria ajudando a comunidade identificando a melhor solução. Só pode aceitar uma delas, mas pode votar em qualquer coisa no site todo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A estrutura de dados que está usando não é ideal para o que você quer fazer. Não sei o motivo de estar usando ArrayList, mas se você precisa que a estrutura não aceite valores repetidos o ideal é usar o Set para não ter que fazer tratamentos adicionais e deixar o código mais limpo.

```
    Set<String> houses = new HashSet<>();

    public void add (String house){
        // nunca aceitará valor repetido
        houses.add(house);
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Você não pode remover itens do objeto sendo iterado, porque ele passa ter outra estrutura durante a iteração iniciada. Tem que criar uma estrutura auxiliar. Se quiser fazer na mão mesmo e não usar um `HashSet`:

```
ArrayList<String> aux = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String item : houses) if (!aux.contains(item)) aux.add(item);
houses = aux;
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/MfuqwB). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/qzstzegs-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Array/Distinct.java).