# Eliminar repetições de valores em ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Tenho o seguinte `ArrayList<Integer>`:

```
ArrayList<Integer> sequencia = new ArrayList<>();
sequencia.add(2);
sequencia.add(11);
sequencia.add(12);
sequencia.add(13);
sequencia.add(14);
sequencia.add(14);
System.out.println(sequencia.toString());
```

Ele retorna isso:

```
[2, 11, 12, 13, 14, 14]
```

Mas quero que fique assim:

```
[2, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

Pois quero, ou eliminar os repetidos ou agrupar os valores.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize [*streams* para filtrar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Program {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> sequencia = new ArrayList<>();
        sequencia.add(2);
        sequencia.add(11);
        sequencia.add(12);
        sequencia.add(13);
        sequencia.add(14);
        sequencia.add(14);
        System.out.println(sequencia.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList()).toString());
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/9pcuFY). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/tgvdwdct-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Array/Distinct.java).

Tem uma [solução mais "manual"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/110802/101) que funciona em versões antes do Java 8. Não gosto dessas soluções de `HashSet`, embora internamente seja provável que o `distinct()` a use, mas pelo menos é um detalhe de implementação.

Comment: Funcionou! Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

O caminho mais simples é você usar uma implementação da interface `Set`. Mais precisamente um [`java.util.TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html).

Por exemplo:

```
Set<Integer> semDuplicidade = new TreeSet<>(sequencia); // sua lista
```